# Seg Faulting SPARC Assembly

Tags: c, sparc

I am determining if a number is zero in my function. If it is zero I need to pass some string like "Is Zero" into the variable I have declared as B. My function to determine if it is zero works but when I try to pass the string into the variable B with my SPARC source code I seg fault.

Here is what I have been trying in my C driver:

```
void display( double, char* );   
char B[100];
double x = 0.000;
display(x, &B);

printf("%s", B);
```

Here is my SPARC code:

```
 ZERO: .asciz "Is Zero\n"



.global display
.section ".text"
.align 4
display:    
         save   %sp, -96, %sp


         mov    %i0, %o0
         mov    %i1, %o1
         mov%i2, %o2

         call   is_zero         ! check if number is zero
         cmp    %o0, 0
         bne    zero
         nop


zero:
        save    %sp, -96, %sp
        set     ZERO, %l0
        ldub    [%l0], %l1
        cmp     %l1, 0          ! exit when zero byte reached
        beq     done
        nop
        stb     %l1, [%i2]
        inc     %l0
        inc     %i2

        ba      zero
        nop
done:
        ret
        restore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

&B is the pointer to char array B.
display function take a char pointer in 2nd parameter.
display(x, &B) should be display(x, B).

Comment: That removes my "passing arg 2 of `classify' from incompatible pointer type" warning when I compile my code but it does not solve the seg fault.

Comment: @Alfred, I propose you write the `display` function in C to test your program. After that, you may convert the `display` function to assembly language.